# Haskell Fold with anonymous function

Tags: haskell, anonymous-function, fold

I have a problem with one of the Haskell basics: Fold + anonymous functions

I'm developing a bin2dec program with `foldl`.
The solution looks like this:

```
bin2dec :: String -> Int
bin2dec = foldl (\x y -> if y=='1' then x*2 + 1 else x*2) 0
```

I understand the basic idea of `foldl` / `foldr` but I can't understand what the parameters `x y` stands for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the type of `foldl`

`foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a`

Consider `foldl f z list`

so foldl basically works incrementally on the list (or anything foldable), taking 1 element from the left and applying `f z element` to get the new element to be used for the next step while folding over the rest of the elements. Basically a trivial definition of foldl might help understanding it.

```
 foldl f z []     = z
 foldl f z (x:xs) = foldl f (f z x) xs
```

The diagram from [Haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Fold) might help building a better intuition.

[image: foldl f z]

Consider your function `f = (\x y -> if y=='1' then x*2 + 1 else x*2)` and try to write the trace for `foldl f 0 "11"`. Here `"11"` is same as `['1','1']`

```
  foldl f 0 ['1','1'] 
= foldl f (f 0 '1') ['1']
```

Now f is a function which takes 2 arguments, first a integer and second a character and returns a integer. 
So In this case `x=0` and `y='1'`, so `f x y = 0*2 + 1 = 1`

```
= foldl f 1 ['1']
= foldl f (f 1 '1') []
```

Now again applying `f 1 '1'`. Here `x=1` and `y='1'` so `f x y = 1*2 + 1 = 3`.

```
= foldl f 3 []
```

Using the first definition of `foldl` for empty list.

```
= 3
```

Which is the decimal representation of "11".

Answer (score 2):

Use the types! You can type `:t` in GHCi followed by any function or value to see its type. Here's what happens if we ask the for the type of `foldl`

```
Prelude> :t foldl
foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
```

The input list is of type `[b]`, so it's  a list of `b`s. The output type is `a`, which is what we're going to produce. You also have to supply an initial value for the fold, also of type `a`. The function is of type

```
a -> b -> a
```

The first parameter (`a`) is the value of the fold computed so far. The second parameter (`b`) is the next element of the list. So in your example

```
\x y -> if y == '1' then x * 2 + 1 else x * 2
```

the parameter `x` is the binary number you've computed so far, and `y` is the next character in the list (either a `'1'` or a `'0'`).

Comment: thanks... my problem was the understanding of anonym functions... i never thought it through...

I think the best working example for this kind of task is

> length = foldl (\x y -> x+1) 0 [1,2,3,4]